# Email codeigniter SMTP error was encountered: 450 4.7.1

Tags: php, codeigniter, envio-de-email

será que vocês podem me explicar como eu envio e-mail de um formulário pelos servidores locaweb, tenho um site de um cliente hospedado na locaweb, porém o formulário de envio não funciona usando o e-mail deles, gostaria de saber se alguém já teve um problema semelhante na locaweb usando o codeigniter e como vocês resolveram.

```
 if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


 $config['protocol']='smtp';
 $config['smtp_host']='smtp.xxx.xxx';
 $config['smtp_port']='587';
 $config['smtp_timeout']='60';
 $config['smtp_user']='xxxxx';
 $config['smtp_pass']='xxxxx';
 $config['charset']='utf-8';
 $config['newline']="\r\n";
 $config['mailtype']="html";
 $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';



    $nome= $this->input->post('nome', TRUE);        
    $empresa = $this->input->post('nome-empresa', TRUE);    
    $telefone = $this->input->post('telefone', TRUE);      
    $celular = $this->input->post('celular', TRUE);
    $email = $this->input->post('email', TRUE);
    $cidade = $this->input->post('cidade', TRUE);
    $bairro = $this->input->post('bairro', TRUE);
    $endereco = $this->input->post('endereco', TRUE);

            $data['email'] = [
                'nome' =>$nome,
                'empresa' =>$empresa,
                'telefone' =>$telefone,
                'celular'  =>$celular,
                'cidade' => $cidade,
                'bairro' => $bairro,
                'endereco' => $endereco,
                'email' => $email    

            ];

            $mensagem = $this->load->view('template_email/index', $data, true);
            $this->email->from($email);  
            $this->email->to('email'); 
            $this->email->subject('Solicitação de Visita');        
            $this->email->message($mensagem);                   
            $this->email->send();     
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

No localhost envia normal com outros servidores smtp, as configurações estão no config/email.php e funcionam, menos na locaweb, como fazer alguém sabe?

O erro retornado é esse:

> The following SMTP error was encountered: 450 4.7.1 : Recipient address rejected: Access Denied Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method

Comment: Aparece algum erro?

Comment: sim The following SMTP error was encountered: 450 4.7.1 : Recipient address rejected: Access Denied 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Answer (score 3):

consegui resolver o problema, na realidade a locaweb tem um sistema de anti-span, quando você envia um e-mail com template html, você não pode deixar o campo de quem envia com o email cadastrado pelo remetente, na realidade, o formulário deve ser enviado por um e-mail do seu dominio, segue o código com a solução abaixo, leve em consideração que estou usando o codeigniter, a biblioteca de e-mail esta sendo carregada pelo autoload, e os arquivos de configuração de email estão em um arquivo email.php dentro da config, que garante que a configuração ja está carregada,

```
  //configuração

  $config['protocol']='smtp';
  $config['smtp_host']='smtp.seudominio.com.br';
  $config['smtp_port']='587';
  $config['smtp_timeout']='60';
  $config['smtp_user']='user@seudominio.com.br';
  $config['smtp_pass']='xxxxx';
  $config['charset']='utf-8';
  $config['newline']="\r\n";
  $config['mailtype']="html";
  $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';


//controller
$nome= $this->input->post('nome', TRUE);        
$empresa = $this->input->post('nome-empresa', TRUE);    
$telefone = $this->input->post('telefone', TRUE);      
$celular = $this->input->post('celular', TRUE);
$email = $this->input->post('email', TRUE);
$cidade = $this->input->post('cidade', TRUE);
$bairro = $this->input->post('bairro', TRUE);
$endereco = $this->input->post('endereco', TRUE);

        $data['email'] = [
            'nome' =>$nome,
            'empresa' =>$empresa,
            'telefone' =>$telefone,
            'celular'  =>$celular,
            'cidade' => $cidade,
            'bairro' => $bairro,
            'endereco' => $endereco,
            'email' => $email    

        ];


        $mensagem = $this->load->view('template_email/index', $data, true);
        $this->email->from('email@seudominio.com.br');  
        $this->email->to('email@seudominio.com.br'); 
        $this->email->reply_to($email); //email de resposta
        $this->email->subject('Solicitação de Visita');        
        $this->email->message($mensagem);                   
        $this->email->send();     
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que faltou iniciar a lib com as configurações.

```
$config['protocol']='smtp';
 $config['smtp_host']='smtp.xxx.xxx';
 $config['smtp_port']='587';
 $config['smtp_timeout']='60';
 $config['smtp_user']='xxxxx';
 $config['smtp_pass']='xxxxx';
 $config['charset']='utf-8';
 $config['newline']="\r\n";
 $config['mailtype']="html";
 $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
 $this->load->library('email', $config);
```

Comment: Olá, a lib já está sendo carregada no autoload do codeigniter, e as configurações estão sendo carregadas pelo email.php na config do codeigniter, por isso no localhost está funcionando normal, porém no server da locaweb não está.

Comment: Então faz o teste, tira do autoload e deixa somente no controller email... Pois trabalho assim com a locaweb e não dá problemas...